# ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit ModalPopupExtender + HTML + JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I have a section of HTML and JavaScript that represent a dialog. The code for this is something like the following:

```
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr><td>My Dialog</td></tr>
  <tr><td>
    [Formula Here]
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

This dialog will open from a link click. Currently, I have the content of the dialog working correctly. I also have the table opening and closing as I would like. However, I do not have it in true dialog form. The project I am working with is using the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit. However, I can't seem to figure out how to take my existing dialog and make it work with the ModalPopupExtender.

Can anyone provide me with an answer of how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I named the id incorrectly :(. Problem fixed.